# Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$StringUri

Tags: java, android

So I keep getting this error "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$StringUri" when I press the buttons that implement the below methods:

```
public void shareItems() {

    StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();

    String name = itemName.getText().toString();
    String price = itemPrice.getText().toString();
    String description = itemDescription.getText().toString();
    String location = itemLocation.getText().toString();


    dataString.append(" product: " + name + "\n");
    dataString.append(" price: " + price + "\n");
    dataString.append(" pick up location: " + location + "\n");
    dataString.append(" description: " + description);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "product for sale");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataString.toString());

    try {

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "share"));

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install a messaging app",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void sendWhatsapp() {

    StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();

    String name = itemName.getText().toString();
    String price = itemPrice.getText().toString();
    String description = itemDescription.getText().toString();
    String location = itemLocation.getText().toString();


    dataString.append(" product: " + name + "\n");
    dataString.append(" price: " + price + "\n");
    dataString.append(" pick up location: " + location + "\n");
    dataString.append(" description: " + description);

    Items item = new Items();
    item.setMobile(adapter.getMobile());
    mobile = item.getMobile();
    System.out.println(mobile);


    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "0542001117");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataString.toString());
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");



    try {

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Contact seller"));

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install WhatsApp",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

The don't use any Uri's at all. It says the error is in this class, which implements serialiazable but I don't see how it's causing the problem, or how it's triggered by those buttons.

```
public class Items implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 10L;
private String itemDescription;
private String itemLocation;
private Uri itemImage;
private String itemName;
private int itemPrice;
private int itemID;
private String mobile;


public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}

public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}



public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}



public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}



public int getItemPrice() {
    return itemPrice;
}

public void setItemPrice(int itemPrice) {
    this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
}



public int getItemID() {
    return itemID;
}

public void setItemID(int itemID) {
    this.itemID = itemID;
}



public String getItemDescription() {
    return itemDescription;
}

public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}

public String getItemLocation() {
    return itemLocation;
}

public void setItemLocation(String itemLocation) {
    this.itemLocation = itemLocation;
}

public Uri getItemImage() {
    return itemImage;
}

public void setItemImage(Uri itemImage) {
    this.itemImage = itemImage;
}



public Items( String item, int price, int id, String description, String location, Uri image, String phone){

    itemName = item;
    itemPrice = price;
    itemID = id;
    itemDescription = description;
    itemLocation = location;
    itemImage = image;
    mobile = phone;
}

public Items(){

}
```

}

Edit: This is where I'm using serializable:

```
public class CustomListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

private int layoutResource;
private Activity activity;
static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Context context;

private ArrayList<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

public CustomListviewAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<Items> data) {
    super(act, resource, data);
    layoutResource = resource;
    activity = act;
    itemList = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Items getItem(int position) {
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Items item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;


    if ( row == null || (row.getTag() == null)) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.itemName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.itemPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calories);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        row.setTag(holder);

    }else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    holder.item = getItem(position);

    holder.itemName.setText(holder.item.getItemName());
    holder.itemImage.setImageURI(holder.item.getItemImage());
    holder.itemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(holder.item.getItemPrice()));



    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft =
                    ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

            ItemDetails frag = new ItemDetails();

            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putSerializable("userObj", finalHolder.item);

            frag.setArguments(mBundle);
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();



        }
    });


    return row;

}

public class ViewHolder {
    Items item;
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemPrice;
    ImageView itemImage;

}
```

}

and in the class where the methods that cause the crash:

```
public class ItemDetails extends Fragment {


private View view;
private TextView itemName, itemLocation, itemPrice, itemDescription;
private ImageView itemImage;
private Button shareButton, sendWhatsapp;
private int itemId;
private DataBaseAdapter adapter;
private String mobile;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_details, container, false);
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detsItemName);
    itemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detsPrice);
    itemLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detsItemLocation);
    itemDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detsDescription);
    itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
    shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.detsShare);
    sendWhatsapp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendWhatsappBtn);

    Bundle mBundle = getArguments();

    Items item = (Items) mBundle.getSerializable("userObj");
    itemName.setText(item.getItemName());
    itemPrice.setText(valueOf(item.getItemPrice()));
    itemLocation.setText(item.getItemLocation());
    itemDescription.setText(item.getItemDescription());
    itemImage.setImageURI(item.getItemImage());


    adapter = new DataBaseAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.open();


    itemPrice.setTextSize(34.9f);
    itemPrice.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shareItems();
        }
    });

    sendWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendWhatsapp();
        }
    });


    return view;

}


public void shareItems() {

    StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();

    String name = itemName.getText().toString();
    String price = itemPrice.getText().toString();
    String description = itemDescription.getText().toString();
    String location = itemLocation.getText().toString();


    dataString.append(" المنتج: " + name + "\n");
    dataString.append(" السعر: " + price + "\n");
    dataString.append(" موقع الاستلام: " + location + "\n");
    dataString.append(" الوصف: " + description);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "منتج للبيع");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataString.toString());

    try {

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "شارك"));

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "المرجو تحميل برنامج ارسال",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void sendWhatsapp() {

    StringBuilder dataString = new StringBuilder();

    String name = itemName.getText().toString();
    String price = itemPrice.getText().toString();
    String description = itemDescription.getText().toString();
    String location = itemLocation.getText().toString();


    dataString.append(" المنتج: " + name + "\n");
    dataString.append(" السعر: " + price + "\n");
    dataString.append(" موقع الاستلام: " + location + "\n");
    dataString.append(" الوصف: " + description);

    Items item = new Items();
    item.setMobile(adapter.getMobile());
    mobile = item.getMobile();
    System.out.println(mobile);


    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "0542001117");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataString.toString());
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");



    try {

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "مراسلة البائع"));

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "المرجو تحميل WhatsApp",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

}

Edit again, logcat:

```
--------- beginning of crash
04-19 22:47:13.215 25143-25143/edu.seu.seniorproject.producingfamily 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: edu.seu.seniorproject.producingfamily, PID: 25143

java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing 
serializable object (name = 
edu.seu.seniorproject.producingfamily.item_details.Items)

at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1447)

at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1395)

at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)

at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)

at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)

at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148)

at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1233)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:564)

at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416)

at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322)

at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)

at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)

at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)

at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)

at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3152)

at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3417)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$StringUri

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)

at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)

at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1442)

at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1395) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665) 

at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) 


at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690) 

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1233) 

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:564) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665) 

at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330) 

at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079) 

at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690) 

at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3152) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3417) 

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok did it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class `Items` you have:

```
private Uri itemImage;
```

If a class implements `Serializable` then all of its member variables need to be able to be serialised which `Uri` cannot.

You have a few options:

**Declare itemImage as transient**

If it doesn't matter to you if itemImage is still set when you deserialize it then you can add the `transient` modifier to it.  This tells java to ignore it when it does the serializing:

```
    private transient Uri itemImage;
```

**Change itemImage to be a String**

Instead of a Uri you could just use a `String` which represents the path of the image.  Depending on the type of the `Uri` and how you use it you might not need it as Uri at all

**Use Parcelable instead of Serializable**

This requires more work as you have to manually create the Parcel but it gives you greater control over how the object is 'serialized'

Answer (score 0):

> It says the error is in this class, which implements serialiazable but I don't see how it's causing the problem

Well, you are trying to serialize a `Uri`, which is not supported. Convert it to and from a string representation. Or, perhaps do not use `Serializable`.